# LINQ Expression Trees and Monotouch Linker

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Does referencing a property through an expression like shown below, prevent the MonoTouch Linker from excluding that symbol (UILabel.Text ins this case)?

```cs
var label = new UILabel();
Expression<Func<string>> foo = () => label.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Unless you're using Reflection it is usually not possible to reference code and end up with the linker removing it.

**Update**

Turns out LINQ expression might very well use reflection, so your code might not work. You can easily do a quick test and see what happens though.

Comment: This bug is related to this question: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12126 so Rolf's comment is not to be taken lightly as I've learned the hard way :-)